# SCORM Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: reactjs, filepath, scorm, scorm1.2, scorm-cloud-api

I have started a blank react project using "npx create-react-app scorm".
I then install "npm react-scorm-provider".
I then install  "npm simple-scorm-packager", and add my scoPackager.js.
I then make a scormCloud account and upload the scorm_package to that.

I get several 404 errors? I thought the documentation was pretty straight forward ,but what am i doing wrong? Is my path wrong?

[react-scorm-provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scorm-provider)

[simple-scorm-packager](https://github.com/lmihaidaniel/simple-scorm-packager)

[image: error inspection on launch]

[image: my scoPackage setting]

Answer (score 0):

I moved,

```
  <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
```

underneath:

```
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
```

in my index.html.

Then I added

```
  "homepage": "./",
```

to my package.json. This seemed to fix my issue when testing in SCORM cloud